# What are the texture coordinates for a tetrahedron

Tags: textures, coordinates, webgl

**EDIT** This is the WebGL code for initializing the tetrahedron points. You may want to skip to the second code block, because you may be able to answer without this.

```
    //Making a tetrahedron with equal sides
    //Using rotation matrices to determine the points

    //-120 degrees
    var q = -Math.PI/2.0 * 4.0/3.0;
    //Transformation matrix for X-axis rotation
    var rotationArrayX = [
        1.0,    0.0,            0.0,            0.0,
        0.0,    Math.cos(q),    Math.sin(q),    0.0,
        0.0,    -Math.sin(q),   Math.cos(q),    0.0,
        0.0,    0.0,            0.0,            1.0
    ];

    var rotationMatrixX = mat4.create(rotationArrayX);
    var d = vec3.create(new Array(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); //Topmost point
    var a = vec3.create();
    mat4.multiplyVec3(rotationMatrixX, d, a);

    //Now we have the top most point and the first point of the base
    //After rotating the vector A with 120 degrees two times, we have the 3 base points

    //120 degrees
    q = -q;
    //Transformation matrix for Y-axis rotation
    var rotationArrayY = [
        Math.cos(q), 0.0, -Math.sin(q),     0.0,
        0.0,         1.0,       0.0,        0.0,
        Math.sin(q), 0.0, Math.cos(q),      0.0,
        0.0,         0.0,       0.0,        1.0
    ];

    var rotationMatrixY = mat4.create(rotationArrayY);

    //Calculating points B and C
    var b = vec3.create();
    mat4.multiplyVec3(rotationMatrixY, a, b);
    var c = vec3.create();
    mat4.multiplyVec3(rotationMatrixY, b, c);

    //The remaining point is the top point

    var vertices = new Array();

    //bottom
    vertices.push(a); vertices.push(b); vertices.push(c);
    //front
    vertices.push(b); vertices.push(c); vertices.push(d);
    //right
    vertices.push(c); vertices.push(a); vertices.push(d);
    //left
    vertices.push(a); vertices.push(b); vertices.push(d);
```

How should I imagine texturing these triangles? Is this a valid set of texture coordinates?

```
    var textureCoords = [
        //bottom
        0.5, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

        //front
        0.5, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

        //right
        0.5, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

        //left
        0.5, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
    ];
```

I based this on http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showpost.php?p=1542703&postcount=2:

```
  -------(0.5,1)-------
  |                   |
  |      Texture      |
  |      Image        |
  |                   | 
  |                   |
(0,0)---------------(1,0)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is: Whatever you want them to be. There isn't a "right answer" here.

In effect, you've asked a question like "I have a tetrahedron, what is the right color?" Nobody can give you a meaningful answer.

You'll need to rephrase the question in a way that can be answered, such as "What are the texture coordinates of the 'bottom' face if I wanted to map the lower half of an image divided along a line extending from the upper-left corner to the bottom-right using OpenGL?"

You're asking someone to type out texture coordinates, which is somewhat silly. Humans really don't do well with visualizing texture coordinates -> image relationships for anything more complicated than say a few triangles, and even then only if they form a simple and/or regular shape. This is why we have programs that allow us to visualize the changes without tediously typing out values.

Also, why does your tetrahedron have 5 faces? A tetrahedron has a triangular base and shares edges with 3 other triangular faces, who all share a common "top" vertex (and thus two edges each). If you've ever playing a pen & paper RPG such as Dungeons and Dragons, it is the canonical "four sided die". Just go Google Image Search "tetrahedron" to see what I mean.

At risk of sounding rude, I'd say it looks like this 'code' suffers from copy-paste syndrome. I think you need to take sometime out to read up on the fundamentals of texture mapping as a concept, maybe write some example that texture maps a single "flat" (parallel to screen) triangle to get some hands-on practice with it. Playing with a 3D editor's UV editor may help as well so you can see real-time changes as you modify the texture coordinates.

Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry about the tetrahedron, i kind of got confused with the code :)